# Is there a list of sites that generate pure random hands?

Tags: hand-history

Been playing poker long before online poker.  Done very well in small tournies both locally and in Vegas.  Moved onto the big pay sites years ago.  Made money for sure but really never gambled enough to quantify the amount of time it took.

Now some of these sites were rigged and it was easy to tell within a few days (usually by me winning some ridiculous hands, being new to site).  I don't want to name them because it is conjecture as I haven't been playing on them for a few years and they might have changed.

This leads me to the reason why I ask my question.   I am bored in the airport and download the WSOP iphone app.  Been playing for a few months off and on.  For the past month have been logging certain hands - yes via spreadsheet.

My hand distribution is WAY off.  But the thing I have seen that is even more off is the prescribed hands.  There are several but two come up with the greatest frequency:

- pair is flopped.  If no one has said pair the frequency of finishing hands is basically normal/random.  Mainly there are a normal amount of straights, flushes, and two pair.  BUT if someone has a match to make trips... this is where it gets interesting.  Flushes go through the roof, straights go up much higher too.   (One of my main -winning- tactics is to call a slow playing trip if I am suited and I get one more on the flop.  I have 38% chance when this should hold at a little more than 10%.  Now if I get two suited on flop to go with mine I enjoy a 65% flush chance.  Funny thing is with the 2 suit flop the chances of another player having the same suited pair sky rockets!  So A2 suited becomes a great hand because it has a great chance of players going all-in.)
- scenario two is the multiple pairs.  I have seen QQ, KK, AA on the same hand 3 times in a day.  One of those included 3 other sets of pairs at a 9 person table - so 6 players paired!  This is hard to deal with because I have a hard time of raising much on KK.

So my point here isn't that WSOP is cheating people or whatever.  It is just really apparent that the cards aren't random.  It seems that they have some prescribed formulas to bump the action.  Are there pay sites that use more sophisticated prescribed hands (not rigged), are there lists of sites with known rigged games, and if so does anyone have data on if there is any favoritism of players?

Edit:  Since this was put on hold I will add more.  I have no idea how this could be primarily opinion based.  Either someone has a list with evidence and it is a good answer or there is nothing and it stays open.  I fail to see how I am asking for any opinions on this question.  Yes the comments may be full of conjecture/opinions but the Q/A should not be.

Further Edit:  I have an additional 15k hands and I am not seeing anything different from the things noted above.  However... I have one stat that I just honed in on.  On all-ins with multiple players I had a variance of "-3%" vs. expected value.  This was measured with over 1200 all-in, multiple players.  This is a good 1 SD difference but within the realms of just a bad streak.

Now all-ins vs 1 player.  Holy crap!!  If I had an all-in with at least one card not showing I had an expected winning percentage of 69.6%.  This is rather high because I am conservative and I usually will not go all-in preflop unless late in round and blinds are big.  My all-in winning percentage vs 1 other player on over 1900 hands (with at least 1 card not showing) is 39.2%.  There is nothing statistically possible about this.  To make matters even worse my all-in vs 1 player with 1 card left was an expected win 84.5% of the time and I only win 53.6%.  I would have to really do a deep dive into the stats but this points to a killer (rigged) river.

Comment: What evidence do you have that it's rigged? You're not recording every hand I assume, and I guarantee you if you put in a substantial volume, 250,000+ hands, and track every hand you'll find your frequencies are pretty spot on to the ideal mathematical probability. You get fluctuations of course because that's probability over the short term. Don't forget online you see much more hands per hour than live, so it might seem like you're getting worse beats in an hour.

Comment: I think it would take more  "logging certain hands for a month via a spreadsheet" to come to any statistically significant conclusions. I don't see how it would benefit WSOP to rig deals.  Darvin Moon got a nice run of cards at the 2009 World Series of Poker and I don't think that was rigged.

Comment: @Grinch91 - got 7k hands logged.  Again not saying it is rigged.  Saying there are prescribed trends in hand pattern - meaning not random.  Most of my data is 5-6 SD away from mean.  The problem is I would need either opposite data or 30k more hands at a normal distribution to get back to maybe this is random.

Comment: 7k hands isn't enough to be honest to make a call on a pattern. It's not truly random, computers, currently, can't do true randomness. It's as close to as random as can be, but it's always going to be limited by the programming of it. There isn't enough space in a comment box to explain exactly how you computers handle random number generation in detail. But to put it very simply, an algorithm does something to spit out a number, and this algorithm is fed a set of data which acts as a seed for the randomness.

Comment: They're making rake regardless and thousands of hands are happening every hour, that it actually goes against them to stack the deck so to speak. If people don't trust the site people won't play. Sounds like you just experienced a spike is all. Maybe if you keep tracking and have a much larger sample size then it might hold a bit of weight.

Comment: @Grinch91 - I can keep tracking but I don't think much will change and I can certainly check in.  #1 this is not a pay site.  #2 I have already used these patterns as an easy (fake) money maker.  The patterns were vividly noticeable within the first few weeks of playing (from 20+ years of experience).   When I started collecting data I was laughing.  As for your comments on why a site would do this.  Easy.  Bad players play out their draws to the bone.  The site is upping the bad players' odds by hitting more straights and flushes.

Comment: Not buying that upping straights and flushes would increase bad player enjoyment.

Comment: It's not about keeping bad players happy or lucky. It's about keeping loyal players playing. The practice you're describing is a quick way to alienate loyal players and piss them off. These new players aren't tested and it's a big risk for them to give them better odds, because whats to stop them from winning and cashing out never to play again. Site's really don't operate like this.

Comment: @Grinch91 - You are not getting it.  It is not a real money site.  You can buy chips but there is no cash out.  So yes they want you to lose because you might buy "chips".  If you don't lose you don't buy because you have chips.  Also I disagree with your assumptions you are making about other sites too.  You can certainly prescribe hands without pissing off the regulars - especially if the regulars figure it out.

Comment: @blankip When someone loses chips someone else wins.  First it was to keep beginners interested and now it is to force you to buy chips?  Well you *figured* it out and are looking for other sites.

Comment: @Paparazzi - that's not the point of the question.  I am just wondering how prescribed hands work and how many sites do it.  I could care less about winning or losing on this site, I find the hand selection fascinating.  I have for year witnessed it online but never to the detail of this site.  Even more fun and picking out which people got caught be the trips/straight/flush all in the same hand multiple times per tourney.

Comment: I don't see the point to the question either.  I don't buy your assertion they do it nor your reasons why they might do it.

Comment: One last comment from me, but there is literally 0 evidence, and lets not forget that poker is now regulated online, (I'm aware only in a few places state side). Every aspect of their operations is under regulation to ensure a fair game. Prescribed hands goes directly against a fair game...Forget about an argument of  loyal players or anything to do with the players, lets look at it from a business side. By them potentially prescribing hands they're risking their entire business. I've worked for WSOP, I can tell you they like their paperwork and following regulations to a T. It makes no sense

Comment: As @Grinch91 said a computer cannot do randomness.  At least until we have AI.  With that being said given enough dedication and time someone could figure out every single hand dealt down to the second if they figure out the pattern, and I honestly wouldn't be surprised if some people already have algorithms down to predict the order of the entire deck and who has what cards and what will be dealt.  That is why I don't trust online poker.

Comment: @JamesWilson A computer cannot do randomness?  The NSA and other security agencies are generating LOTS of truly random keys.  A truly random key is not trivial but it does not require AI.

Comment: There is no such thing as truly randomness unless you fall back to QM (and you considering truly random the facts or just a matter of plain old statistics) or external noise capturing (which is not random but macroscopic). Anyway, while true randomness does not exist, there are enough sources of entropy to get it near enough to true randomness.

Comment: @Paparazzi A computer cannot do true randomness.  It can create an algorithm that is VERY hard to crack, but will eventually show a pattern.  True randomness does not show a pattern.  Lets not a forget a program can only do what it is programmed to do.  If you ask it for a random number it must follow a set of code to generate that number, this can be done through a seed, time or some other method.  But, again we are telling the computer to pick this number based on something, thus, it may appear random to the end user, but to the program itis simply following directions.

Comment: @JamesWilson What ever you say.    So atmospheric noise is not random?

Comment: @Paparazzi you're still telling a computer to produce numbers based on a set of data, and can thus still be cracked, albeit hard to near impossible.  This will appear as random and is as probably as close as you can get until artificial intelligence.  And even with atmospheric noise if you're not careful can still produce patterns.  "True" randomness is dropping a die and not knowing the result until the die stops.  As soon as the data is fed into the computer the result is known.

Comment: @JamesWilson What ever you say.  NSA seems to be getting along.

Answer (score 1):

Go to hhsmithy.com  Buy 1 billion hands of the site you think is rigged.  Do this to gather real evidence regarding what you are talking about.  Then start winning with all the info you have!